# C# Dataset Dynamically Add DataColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, dataset

I am trying to add a extra column to a dataset after a query has completed and populate that new column with data.  I have a database relationship of the following:

```
    EmployeeGroups
     /        \    
 Groups       Employees
```

**Empoyees** holds all the data for that individual, I'll name the unique key the UserID.

**Groups** holds all the groups that a employee can be a part of, i.e. Super User, Admin, User; etc.  I will name the unique key GroupID

**EmployeeGroups** holds all the associations of which groups each employee belongs too. (UserID | GroupID)

What I am trying to accomplish is after querying for all users I want to loop though each user and add what groups that user is a part of by adding a new column to the dataset named 'Groups' with a typeof string to insert the groups that user is a part of. Then by use of databinding populate a listview with all employees and their group associations

My code is as follows;  Position 5 is the new column I am trying to add to the dataset.

```
string theQuery = "select UserID, FirstName, LastName, EmployeeID, Active from Employees";
DataSet theEmployeeSet = itsDatabase.runQuery(theQuery);
        DataColumn theCol = new DataColumn("Groups", typeof(string));
        theEmployeeSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add(theCol);
        foreach (DataRow theRow in theEmployeeSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            theRow.ItemArray[5] = "1234";
        }
```

At the moment, the code will create the new column but when i assign the data to that column nothing will be assigned, what am I missing?

If there is any further explination or information I can provide, please let me know.

Thank you all

***EDIT***
Changed Database diagram, was wrong

Comment: I accidentally missed adding the question part when I was in process of formatting the question.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use itemarray you must set all values at once.
so :

```
theRow.ItemArray = new object[] { x,y,z,s,d };
```

I agree it is not clear that you should use it that way..
I guess the getter makes a copy of the data and you fill element 5 of that copy

You should do :

```
theRow["Groups"] = "1234"
```

Or :

```
theRow[5] = "1234"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's relational integrity between your employees/groups and associations, you can put the tables in a `DataSet`, add `DataRelation`s to define the relationships between the tables, and then create `DataColumn`s in the association table that use `DataColumn.Expression` to look up values from the related tables.  This will give you an `EmployeeGroups` table that can display each employee and group name.

Tragically, if you want to go the other way, i.e. create a column in the Employees table that aggregates together all of its groups (which is what you're describing), you can't do it with an expression.  In that case, it probably is easiest to do what you describe, and add a column to the Employees table.  But LINQ makes populating that column pretty simple, and if you've already created the relations between the tables, and the columns in the EmployeeGroups table that get the employee and group names, so much the better.

Which brings us to this.  Here's a class that creates and populates a data set with Employees, Groups, and EmployeeGroups tables.  It creates relations between the association table and the other two tables, which `DataColumn.Expression` and `DataRow.GetChildRows` need in order to do their magic.  It also exposes the tables as `IList` types that WPF can bind to:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace JoinAndGroupDemo
{
    public class DataSource
    {
        private DataSet _DS;

        public DataSource()
        {
            CreateDataSet();
        }

        private void CreateDataSet()
        {
            _DS = new DataSet();
            DataTable emp = _DS.Tables.Add("Employees");
            DataTable grp = _DS.Tables.Add("Groups");
            InitTable(emp);
            InitTable(grp);

            DataTable assoc = _DS.Tables.Add("EmployeeGroups");
            assoc.Columns.Add("empId", typeof (int));
            assoc.Columns.Add("grpId", typeof (int));

            _DS.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("FK_EmployeeGroups_Employees", 
                emp.Columns["id"], assoc.Columns["empId"]));
            _DS.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("FK_EmployeeGroups_Groups", 
                grp.Columns["id"], assoc.Columns["grpId"]));

            assoc.Columns.Add("emp_name");
            assoc.Columns["emp_name"].Expression = "Parent(FK_EmployeeGroups_Employees).name";
            assoc.Columns.Add("grp_name");
            assoc.Columns["grp_name"].Expression = "Parent(FK_EmployeeGroups_Groups).name";

            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Malcolm Reynolds"});
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Zoe Washburne" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Hoban Washburne" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Irina Serra" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Jayne Cobb" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, "Kaylee Frye" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, "Simon Tam" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, "River Tam" });
            emp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, "Derrial Book" });

            grp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Command"});
            grp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Combat" });
            grp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Operations" });
            grp.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Other" });

            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 2 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, 2 }); // spoiler alert!
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 3 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, 3 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 4 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, 4 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, 4 });
            assoc.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, 4 });

            emp.Columns.Add("groups", typeof (string));
            foreach (DataRow empRow in emp.Rows)
            {
                empRow["groups"] = string.Join(
                    ", ",
                    empRow
                        .GetChildRows("FK_EmployeeGroups_Employees")
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => (string) x["grp_name"])
                        .ToArray());
            }

            grp.Columns.Add("employees", typeof(string));
            foreach (DataRow grpRow in grp.Rows)
            {
                grpRow["employees"] = string.Join(
                    ", ",
                    grpRow
                        .GetChildRows("FK_EmployeeGroups_Groups")
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => (string)x["emp_name"])
                        .ToArray());
            }
        }

        private void InitTable(DataTable t)
        {
            t.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
            t.Columns.Add("name", typeof (string));

            // this is required by DataRelations
            t.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { t.Columns["id"]};
        }

        public IList Employees
        {
            get
            { return ((IListSource)_DS.Tables["Employees"]).GetList(); }
        }

        public IList Groups
        {
            get { return ((IListSource)_DS.Tables["Groups"]).GetList(); }
        }

        public IList EmployeeGroups
        {
            get { return ((IListSource)_DS.Tables["EmployeeGroups"]).GetList(); }            
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML for a Window that displays all this information:

```
<Window x:Class="JoinAndGroupDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JoinAndGroupDemo"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DataSource x:Key="DataSource"/>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Navy"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
   </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel DataContext="{StaticResource DataSource}">
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">Employees</Label>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Groups" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=groups}"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">Groups</Label>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=id}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Employees" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=employees}"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel>
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">Employee groups</Label>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeGroups}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Employee" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=emp_name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=grp_name}"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```